# ViewComponent not happy about my query

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I'm struggeling to get a grasp on ViewComponents. I have this ViewComponent class for a shopping cart:

```
public class ShoppingCartViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private readonly MyStoreContext _context;

    public ShoppingCartViewComponent(MyStoreContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(int Id)
    {
        return View(await GetCartAsync(Id));
    }

    private Task<ViewModelShoppingCart> GetCartAsync(int Id)
    {
        var VMCart = _context.ShoppingCarts
                    .Where(c => c.Id == Id)
                    .Select(cart => new ViewModelShoppingCart
                    {
                        Id = cart.Id,
                        Title = cart.Title,
                        CreateDate = cart.CreateDate,
                        ShoppingCartItems = cart.ShoppingCartItems
                                            .Select(items => new ViewModelShoppingCartItem
                                            {
                                                ProductId = items.ProductId,
                                                ProductTitle = items.Product.Title,
                                                ProductPrice = items.Product.Price,
                                                Quantity = items.Quantity
                                            }).ToList()
                    }).FirstOrDefault();
        return VMCart;
    }
}
```

This causes a build error on `return VMCart`, with this message from VS:

`Cannot implicitly convert type
'System.Linq.IQueryable<MyStore.Models.ViewModels.ViewModelShoppingCart>'
to
'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<MyStore.Models.ViewModels.ViewModelShoppingCart>'.
An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

What am I doing wrong? **EDIT** Added .FirstOrDefault() at the end of my query, but the error remains the same.

Comment: Add `.FirstOrDefault()` to that query. (It has nothing to do with viewcomponents.)

Comment: @GSerg I added .FirstOrDefault() to my query, but the error remains the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your function definition looks like you're trying to make an async method but nothing internally is async. Change it to this:

```
private async Task<ViewModelShoppingCart> GetCartAsync(int Id)
{
    var VMCart = await _context.ShoppingCarts
                .Where(c => c.Id == Id)
                .Select(cart => new ViewModelShoppingCart
                {
                    Id = cart.Id,
                    Title = cart.Title,
                    CreateDate = cart.CreateDate,
                    ShoppingCartItems = cart.ShoppingCartItems
                                        .Select(items => new ViewModelShoppingCartItem
                                        {
                                            ProductId = items.ProductId,
                                            ProductTitle = items.Product.Title,
                                            ProductPrice = items.Product.Price,
                                            Quantity = items.Quantity
                                        }).ToList()
                }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    return VMCart;
}
```

Or make it not async:

```
private ViewModelShoppingCart GetCart(int Id)
{
    var VMCart = _context.ShoppingCarts
                .Where(c => c.Id == Id)
                .Select(cart => new ViewModelShoppingCart
                {
                    Id = cart.Id,
                    Title = cart.Title,
                    CreateDate = cart.CreateDate,
                    ShoppingCartItems = cart.ShoppingCartItems
                                        .Select(items => new ViewModelShoppingCartItem
                                        {
                                            ProductId = items.ProductId,
                                            ProductTitle = items.Product.Title,
                                            ProductPrice = items.Product.Price,
                                            Quantity = items.Quantity
                                        }).ToList()
                }).FirstOrDefault();
    return VMCart;
}
```